# How to fetch the TTL in a PassiveExpiringMap

Tags: java, collections

I initialised a `PassiveExpiringMap` as follows:

```
Map<String, Boolean> expiringMap;
expiringMap = new PassiveExpiringMap<>(1000));
```

Now, later I want to fetch the TTL (1000 here). How can I go about doing that? I found that there is something called [expirationTime](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/PassiveExpiringMap.ConstantTimeToLiveExpirationPolicy.html#expirationTime(K,%20V)), but not being able to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible (unless you resort to some kind of a solution involving reflection).

Once you create a `PassiveExpiringMap` instance passing the TTL, it creates an `ExpirationPolicy` (`ConstantTimeToLiveExpirationPolicy`) passing the TTL to it. The TTL is stored in the instance variable [`timeToLiveMillis`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.groupbyinc/common-utils/23/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/PassiveExpiringMap.java#84) which is *private*.

The `expirationTime` you mentioned is used to compute the expiration time of an Object (which is nothing but the current time in milliseconds + the TTL you passed). It is computed when you insert an object into the map.

---

One way is to create a wrapper object that holds the `PassiveExpiringMap` and the TTL like

```
class ExpiringMapWithTTL {
    private Map<String, Boolean> expiringMap; 
    private long ttl;
    //Builder or Getters, Setter
}
```